# C# FakeItEasy fake method that have been overrided

Tags: c#, mocking, fakeiteasy

I have problem with faking my class:

Class A has a method:

```
protected virtual int method(int argument)
{
    implementation
    return int;
}
```

Class B extends class A and overrides the method:

```
protected override int method(int argument)
{
      int result = base.method(argument);
      implementation
      return result + 1;
}
```

I need to mock class B and test the `method` function. The problem is that I need to avoid calling the `base.method(argument)` function. I just need to test my method implementation, and mock that function to return an int.

How can I do it with FakeItEasy? Or other mocking frameworks?

**UPDATE**

Problem solved by:
making function:

```
int MethodCaller(int argument)
{
    base.method(argument);
}
```

and executing it in my class B "method" function. Than mocking MethodCaller function

Comment: Maybe it better to use incapsulation insted of inheretence here.

Comment: The problem is that "method" function is called by another public function in class A interface, so i cant change it's signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with helper class + one more helper method, but I realy don't like this solution:

```
public class A
{
    protected virtual int method(int argument)
    {
        return argument;
    }

    public int result(int argument)
    {
      return method(argument);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override int method(int argument)
    {
        return baseMetod(0) + 1;
    }

    protected virtual int baseMetod(int argument)
    {
      return base.method(argument);
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    protected override int baseMetod(int argument)
    {
      return 5;
    }
}
```

so in test you can call `new C().Result(10)`